# Referencing a checkbox value from HTML to C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I have a checkbox on my .cshtml page that when it is checked I want it to NOT send and e-mail to the user. Below is the various pages of code that I have to transfer the boolean value from the .cshtml page to the .cs mailer code but somewhere the value is not transferring. Please help.

In View.cshtml I put the checkbox in:

```
<input class="checkbox_priority" id="no_emails" name="no_emails" type="checkbox" value="true" title="This only applies to the 'Complete' button"/>Do not send e-mail to requestor.
```

In Notification.cs I get/set the value:

```
public virtual Boolean no_emails { get; set; } //Used to not send an e-mail to the creator of a request.
```

And then finally I put the IF statement into the mailer code on RequestService.cs:

```
[Spring.Transaction.Interceptor.Transaction]
    public int Create(int requestId, Policy.Models.Review newReview)
    {
        Policy.Models.Request request;
        Policy.Models.Review review;

        request = RequestDao.Get(requestId);
        newReview.Id = ReviewDao.Save(newReview);

        //Refresh review object
        review = ReviewDao.Get(newReview.Id);
        request.Review = review;

        //Associate review to request
        RequestDao.Update(request);

        //Notify request's author of a response
        string message = "The response to your <a href=\"{0}\">request</a> has been started";
        if (!review.Status.IsActive && !no_emails)
            message = "The response to your <a href=\"{0}\">request</a> has been completed";
        Helpers.Notifier.CreateNotification(request.Author, request, string.Format(message, Helpers.Link.RequestLink(request.Id)));

        return newReview.Id;
    }
```

CreateNotification is defined in a seperate file titled Notifier.cs

```
public static void CreateNotification(IList<Policy.Models.User> recipients, Policy.Models.AAuditable subject, string message)
    {
        if (recipients != null && recipients.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < recipients.Count; ++i)
            {
                CreateNotification(recipients[i], subject, message);
            }
        }
    }

    public static Policy.Models.Notification CreateNotification(Policy.Models.User recipient, Policy.Models.AAuditable subject, string message)
    {

        Policy.Models.Notification note = new Policy.Models.Notification();
        note.Description = message;
        note.IsRead = false;
        note.User = recipient;
```

However, it is saying that no_emails does not exist in the current context. How do I get the code to recognize no_emails has a boolean value from the .cshtml page?

Comment: Try changing the check box name to "no_emails"

Comment: I assume you mean in the line `if (!review.Status.IsActive && !no_emails)`? - where have you passed the value of `no_emails` to that method? Its a property of class `Notification` and nowhere in the method do you refer to anything related t that class - the only model you have is `Review`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a scope issue to me. I would need to see more of your code to be sure but let's assume that there is an instance of Notification that is created in RequestService. You can't directly access the variable no_emails. You would access like this:

```
// here is the instance of notification
Notification someNotifacation = new Notification();

// call the getter method to get the value
if(!someNotification.no_emails)
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: What part of the code would you like to see more of? I edited my post to include more, let me know if there is something specific that you can think of.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing with the form when it is submitted. Could you put the variable no_emails in the request object? Then you could check the value of it in the Create method.

Answer (score 0):

If this is ASP.NET MVC, you can put the `no_emails` variable in the Action parameter list, and MVC will bind it for you to the POSTed form value. However, the parameter name and the `name` attribute on the form must match. Here, you have `name="emails"`, so you will need to change it to match the parameter name you use.

but you have a Spring attribute which makes me think this is not ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: This is not my code I am just modifying it. I am fairly certain though that it is ASP.NET MVC.